# Which javascript code is more efficient when you want to search for multiple HtmlObject with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I try to find out which javascript code is more efficient, for example when I searching several JavaScript span.

this mode with jquery:

```
$('span[value='+value+']')
```

or this mode with standar javascript:

```
function gEBI(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var spans = gEBI("content").getElementsByTagName('span'); 
for (i = 0; i < this.spans.length; i++)
 { 
     if (this.spans[i].getAttribute("value") == valueThis ) { // operations } 
 }
```

one more question that searches are usually more efficient jquery or standard JavaScript

Comment: Definitely the pure JS one. But it *can* be optimized, however.

Comment: The jQuery version would probably be better written as `$("span").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == value })`

Comment: Create a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com), then let us know which one is faster. (Then, someone else will come along and point out all the edge cases invalidating the benchmark.)

Comment: @KevinB: Won't that stop `querySelectorAll()` being used in supported browsers (i.e make it slower in most cases?).

Comment: Make sure you have a fair comparison in your jsperf. $('span[value=' + value + ']') is not similar to gEBI('content').getElementsByTagName(), you would at least have to use $('#content span[value=' + value + ']').

Comment: `$('#content').find('span[value='+value+']')` would be a better jquery comparison

Comment: @Roonaan You misread the code. (There are problems with the code, but they are not really relevant to the overall performance question at hand.)

Comment: @Matt Sure, but do span elements have value attributes? I guess you could make one up,

Comment: @KevinB: http://jsfiddle.net/8ezAJ/. Not sure if that's x-browser though...

Comment: You can also do `$("span").filter("[value='+value+');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern browsers (IE8 and later), jQuery will be far faster than searching through the DOM manually.

Modern browsers support `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, which allow for nodes to be found using CSS queries and is far, far faster than the older DOM methods. jQuery uses those features if they're available so it benefits from the speed boost.

However, if you're really going for speed, don't need ancient browser support, and are only using basic CSS2.1-level queries (such as the one you have there), use querySelector directly. This will be faster than jQuery:

```
// If you only need just one
var span = document.querySelector('span[value='+value+']');
// If there's more than one span like that
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span[value='+value+']');
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector